# If $N \lhd G, (G : N) = 100, a \in G, a^{23} = e$, show that $a \in N$.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

I'm having some trouble with a question that my instructor suggested to think about: Let $N \lhd G$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, the index $(G : N) = 100, a \in G, a^{23} = e$. Show that $a \in N$.

My first approach was to use a theorem stating that if $N \lhd G$ where $(G : N) = m$, then $a^m \in N$. From this result, it obviously follows that $a^{100} \in N$.

However, I am a little stuck continuing and would appreciate any hint to guide my way (I am not looking for a complete solution as I'd love to learn this on my own too :D).

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a \not\in N$, then $aN \neq N$. What can you say about the order of the element $aN$ in $G/N$?

Comment: Hopefully if I'm not incorrect, we should have that $aN$ divides the order of the quotient group $G/N$, which is that $aN$ divides $100$.

Comment: @JulianPark: Yep, that's right. But we have some additional information to work with. What is $(aN)^{23}$?

Comment: Again, if I'm not incorrect, $(aN)^{23} = a^{23}N = eN = N$.

Comment: @JulianPark: Yes, that's right. What does $(aN)^{23} = N$ imply about the order of $aN$ in $G/N$?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm uncertain of what it would imply. I may need some time to think about this.

Comment: @JulianPark: $N$ is the identity element of $G/N$. So if $(aN)^{23} = N$, then the order of $aN$ must divide $23$, right? Now combine this with the observation in your first comment that the order of $aN$ must divide $100$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Would it follow that $aN$ divides the lcm of the two numbers?

Comment: @JulianPark: It's true that $o(aN)$ divides $lcm(100,23) = 2300$, but that's not the observation you need. Think of it this way: $o(aN)$ divides $23$ and it divides $100$. Do $23$ and $100$ have any common factors? No, they're relatively prime. So $o(aN)$ must be what number? There is only one number that works.

Comment: Would it follow that $o(aN)=1$ since $23$ and $100$ are relatively prime?

Comment: @JulianPark: That's right, $o(aN) = 1$. This is true if and only if $aN$ is the identity element of $G/N$, which is true if and only if...?

Comment: $aN = N$ (since $N$ is the identity of the factor group $G/N$) $\iff a \in N$?

Comment: @JulianPark: That's right, QED.